# How to merge two sql results

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am not an expert in SQL. I am just a beginner.

**My Table structure:**

Partner table: objectid, partner[which is partner id], partnerfunc

customertable: customerid, customer type

Given is object id.

**Queries**

```
 select partner from partners where object = '352846';
```

It returns 6 paartner informations.

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6

 select partnerfunction from partners where object = '35284624';

 A
 B
 C
 Z
 X
 Y
```

It returns corresponding partner functions.

I need to get customer type from customer table with the help of given data.

```
select customertype from customer where customerid in (select partner from
partners where iobject = '352846');
```

It returns only 4 informations.

```
Owner
Owner
Vendor
Vendor [Remaining two values may be em]
```

I just got confused. I want to print corresponding partner and partnerfunctions so that i can check the result.

First i just changed the above query to as follows

```
 select customertype from customer, iobj_partners where customerid in 
 (select partner from iobj_partners where iobject = '352846') and iobject 
 = '352846';
```

It returns 24 results

```
 owner [12 rows]
 vendor [12 rows]
```

Should i use distinct? Why does it return 24 values? I am really confused with the query i have written. I totally misunderstood the query.

And i tried to print it along with partner and partner functions,

```
 select customertype, partner, partnerfunction  
 from customer, partners
 where customerid in (select partner from partners where iobject =  
 '352846')
 and iobject  = '352846'
 group by customertype, partner, partnerfunction;
```

It returns 12 rows. 6 vendors, 6 owner.

But i understood that it will return as follows

```
 partner     customertype     partnerfunction
 1           owner            A
 2                            B
 3           owner            C
 4                            X
 5           vendor           Y
 6                            Z
```

But it returns more than what i wanted? Please clear my basic doubt

Comment: Feading through once i don't totally understand the wording/problem (perhaps an printout of what you are getting versus what you want). But maybe you are looking to do some type of "JOIN" like SELECT * FROM partners pp LEFT JOIN customers cc ON pp.partnerid=cc.customerid WHERE pp.objectid="35284624"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a `join`, probably an `outer join` to return the null customers:

```
select p.partner, c.customertype, p.partnerfunction
from partner p
    left join customer c on p.partner = c.customerid
where p.object = 352846
```

Here's a pretty good reference:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)